# Gmail Inline Confirm Action Button link does not work

Tags: google-schemas

I want to use the on-click action button (https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/one-click-action#confirm_action) to confirm a newsletter subscription.

I got whitelisted with the following code:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "EmailMessage",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "ConfirmAction",
    "name": "Confirm Subscription",
    "handler": {
      "@type": "HttpActionHandler",
      "url": "http://www.ourdomain.net/newsletter/confirm/somehash"
    }
  },
  "description": "Confirm Subscription"
}
</script>
```

and the sender mail addresses (e.g. info@test-environment.net, info@service-mail.ourdomain.net)

Everything works fine so far - the button shows up and it links to the url provided by the script. But when clicking it, I get the message:

```
Unable to send request to test-environment.net.
```

Why does google send the request to the sender domain of the mail instead to the url provided by the script?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Are you using Bear Tokens (https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/actions/verifying-bearer-tokens)? If yes, you have to request to be whitelisted for this feature as well. You can make another submission (https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google?hl=en) or try sending an email to the person that you were corresponding  with previously.